# Pre-check a box in a Create View in MVC 3 with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, checkboxfor

I'm working on a site using MVC 3 and C#. I have a simple boolean field that is set with a checkbox. I can create and edit just fine and the values of the boolean field update alright. My only question is: Can I make it so the CheckBox is automatically checked when the user reaches the page? It's a more common situation for it to be checked than not, so I'd like to make it that way. Right now I render the check box with:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Tbd)
```

I have tried:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Tbd, new { value = true } )
```

And:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Tbd, new { value = "true" } )
```

Neither of these three change the actual look of the page, but the HTML source is changed a bit (namely the value field for the Check Box input tag changes from: `value = "true"` to `value = "True"`). So these three methods don't work. So again, can I make it so the checkbox is pre-checked when a user reaches a page for the first time? (Do note this is for Creation, in the Edit View if Tbd is true, the check box is checked like it should be)

Comment: What is the value of model.Tbd? If it's not already True, try init it to True and seeing if that makes a difference.

Comment: @asawyer Awesome! That was exactly what I needed! Solved my issue perfectly, I just needed to implement the logic in the Controller instead of the View. Final code: 
`var report = new Report { Tbd = true };`
`return View(report);`

Mind adding the comment as a response so I can check it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value of model.Tbd? If it's not already True, try init it to True and seeing if that makes a difference

Comment: Thanks! Marked as correct! If you're curious about the full code used, check in the above comment. Just had to pass a pre-created instance of my Model with the Tbd field set to true, like asawyer said.